# Expanding multiple nodes of jqgrid treegrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid's treegrid and the data for the child nodes is being loaded on request. 
But when user clicks on a node (say node1) to expand it and immediately clicks on another node  (say node2) then the children of first node (node1) are being displayed for the second node (node2), the icon of node2 changes to show as expanded but it has data of node1's children and collapsing node2 doesn't do anything but collapsing node1 collapses node1's children which are displayed as node2's children.

Did someone else face such a problem? data for jqgrid is adjacency model in json format.

Comment: The demo in "New in version 3.3 -> Tree Grid" of [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) has the same problem. Is this a bug in jqgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in jqGrid. I looked in the code and I think I understand the problem.

Every time the user click on the "expand" icon [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L86-100) will be executed which call `expandRow` and `expandNode` methods. The code of `expandNode` first overwrite the current value of the `treeANode` parameter of jqGrid which are used internally to identify the row after which the new data will be added. Then the `nodeid`, `parentid` (or `n_left` and `n_right` for the `'nested'` grid model) and `n_level` parameters of the new request to the server will be set and after that the `reloadGrid` will be triggered.

The problem is that *later*, during processing of the `reloadGrid` at the beginning of the internal `populate` method, the internal `.grid.hDiv.loading` property will be tested and if it was set be the *previous still pending* request then the second reloading of the grid will be skipped. The problem is that the value of the `treeANode` parameter is already changed. So the items returned as the children of the first expending node will be added as clidren of the last clicked node.

As the bug fix I suggest to modify [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L425) of code to the following

```
} else if (!this.grid.hDiv.loading) {
```

In the way the `treeANode` parameter will be not overwritten by the click on the second if another pending request is still processing.

You can download from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-treeANode.js) the modified version of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and test whether the problem will be solved after the bug fix. If it will solve the problem I'll post the corresponding bug report with my suggestion how to fix the problem on [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/).

As another workaround you can use `loadui: 'block'` option of jqGrid which will not allow any user interactions during the processing of the pending requests to the server.

Comment: I was going through the code too and yes not allowing the change of node2 as you suggested works, but if the fix can come at in the reloadGrid method then jqgrid can support simultaneous expand nodes. Thanks Oleg, I knew you could help :), but the better fix will be if multiple expand nodes is supported.

Comment: @user976634: I agree that it would be better if simultaneous ajax requests will be permitted, but it's implementation will follows large changes in many jqGrid modules. So I suggest first to fix the existing bug.

Comment: @user976634: I posed [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/child-nodes-are-added-to-the-wrong-parent-node/#p25778) to be sure that Tony will read about the problem and the suggested bug fix.